# dart: reflect methods of a class, no luck with the reflect*() functions

Tags: dart, methods, reflection, dart-mirrors

I'm trying to list the methods of a class, but neither reflectClass() nor reflectType() return anything useful. Has anyone done this already?

This is my code:

```
import 'package:mylib/mylib.dart' as mylib;
import 'dart:mirrors' as mirrors;

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  var reflectedMyClass = mirrors.reflectType(mylib.MyClass);
  // how to list the methods in MyClass here?
}
```

Comment: "return anything useful" does tell us anything about what you want. Please provide an example of what you have tried and explain why the result is not good enough and what you want the code to return instead.

Comment: OK, have (hopefully) clarified now...

Comment: Did not help. You are saying you are not getting the result you expect. Could you post an example which we can run and which does not return what you want. Then tell us what result you want instead.

Comment: I'd need to get the list of methods of the mylib.MyClass class and print their names (and possibly parameter types. The class could be any class.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, mirrors.reflectClass(someClass).declarations.values is the answer. This stuff was not visible in the debugger window where I was stuck, but a null _declarations instead. Going through completions sometimes seems more helpful than the debugger.